# How to add a boolean column to the dataframe that indicates whether each holiday date belongs to the dates column

Tags: r, boolean-logic

I have a dataframe with a sequence of dates, and I want to add a column to the dataframe so that it indicates TRUE if each dates of a vector dates belongs to that sequence of dates and FALSE otherwise.

This is my approach:

```
date <- data_frame(ds = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-12-31'), by = 'day'))

is_holiday <- function(ds) {
  dates <- as.Date(ds)
  as.Date(c('2017-01-01', '2019-07-20')) %in% dates
}
```

where the vector `c` is the vector that i want to check in the column dataframe.

I want to see something like

```
ds          is_holiday
2017-01-01    TRUE
2017-01-02    FALSE
...
2019-07-19    FALSE
2019-07-20    TRUE
2019-07-21    FALSE
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
holidays <- as.Date(c('2017-01-01', '2019-07-20', '2020-01-01'))
date$is_holiday <- FALSE
date$is_holiday[which(date$ds %in% holidays)] <- TRUE
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
date$is_holiday <- ifelse(date$ds %in% holidays, TRUE, FALSE)
```

And per @Ronak's comment below, here's an even simpler one-liner:

```
date$is_holiday <- date$ds %in% holidays
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! I've added that into the answer now. Thanks!